# what is .reporting-* and .monitoring-* index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I see some indexes (.reporting-* and .monitoring-*) as follows in our elasticsearch cluster,

```
green open .monitoring-kibana-7-2022.02.22 FPl-nNnAQE-8aawMEVWoaw 3 1    8640      0   4.2mb   2.1mb
green open .reporting-2020.11.15           4rS-SCGGGS-7YKg28FdyFw 1 1      30      1 323.2mb 161.6mb
green open .reporting-2021.05.09           7wnfwIsSe4rQC5hBFC3o2g 1 1      14      0 324.3mb 162.1mb
```

1. What are these indexes and how do they get created?
2. Do I need these indexes? Can I delete them?
3. How do I stop the creation of such indexes?

Some of the references which I checked are.

**(for .monitoring-* indexes):**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/xpack-introduction.html

**(for .reporting-* indexes):**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-settings-kb.html

This is what my kibana.yml looks like:

````
server.host: ffb-supply-kibana-server
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://master-2:9200","http://master-3:9200","http://fdata-1:9200","http://data-2:9200","http://data-3:9200"]
kibana.index: ".kibana"
elasticsearch.username: "something"
elasticsearch.password: "something"
xpack.reporting.csv.maxSizeBytes: 52428800
logging.quiet: true```
````

Answer (score 4):

The `.monitoring-*` indexes contain monitoring data from any component of the stack that [is monitored](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/monitor-elasticsearch-cluster.html). If you don't enable/setup the monitoring, then those indexes are not created.

The `.reporting*` indexes contain [reports you've setup in Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-getting-started.html). If you don't use those reporting features, the index doesn't get created.

Do you need them? Odds are that if you're asking what they are, you don't really need them.

Can you delete them? Yes, but if you don't disable monitoring, new `.monitoring` indexes are going to appear 10 seconds later again. Same for `.reporting*`, if you or someone else runs a report in Kibana, the index is going to recreated again.

As mentioned earlier, to stop the creation of monitoring indexes, you need to disable monitoring (see first link), but it's not necessarily a good idea to do so, because you'd be blind and not really know how your cluster is doing. However, it's always a good idea to store monitoring data in a different cluster than the production one.

To stop the creation of reporting indexes, you simply need to stop creating reports.

Comment: So to stop .monitoring-* indices just deleting the template for .monitoring-* template is enough? Can I apply something like delete indices older than n days with XYZ pattern?

Comment: if you want to stop those indexes to appear, you need to disable the monitoring altogether, otherwise they are going to keep coming because every 10 second a monitoring probe is being indexed

Comment: Where to disable the monitoring?

Comment: It depends on how it is set up for you, see the first link I shared